How to hide the semi-transparent background for text box in WebVTT subtitles?

When playing a web video with .vtt subtitles, a dark semi-transparent background box is being displayed behind the whole text block (please see the screenshot). Is there a way to hide or remove this background via CSS formatting?
This didn't help:
video::cue {
    background: none;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;

The 'background-image' switch didn't help also, as it has to do with the background for the text lines, and not the entire text block. So is there a way to hide the text-block background?
